# How to build a feature vector out of data combining numbers and strings?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I'm new to machine learning and would appreciate some guidence. I'm doing product categorization, using a database of 25,000 products. each product consists of: name ,description, price, image, and few more numeric features.

I'm not sure how to deal with a combination of text and numeric features. regarding the text part, i read about "bag of words" but if i do that i'll have thousands of features for only the name and description fields, and i'm not sure if that's the right way to go- wouldn't it make the numeric features irrelevant?

how would you create a vector out of this data?

p.s i'm going to test 2 classifiers to examine their results- SVM and KNN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with Sparse Matrices and multiple numerical features when training algorithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300918/dealing-with-sparse-matrices-and-multiple-numerical-features-when-training-algor)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert them numbers using LabelEncoder and then apply the machine learning algorithms.

```
Example- column - city has data->ab,bf,cd,bf,gr,ab
```

Now i can convert them into

```
 form-> 1,2,3,2,4,1
```

Use :

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
col= le.fit_transform(["ab","bf","cd","bf","gr","ab" ])
```